# NSAppleMusicUsageDescription - Missing Info.plist key

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8

I added the key the email suggested and also added the one that is on the drop down list.

I cleaned the project. I am at a loss as to what else to try.

This is the email from Apple:

> Missing Info.plist key - This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSAppleMusicUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You are already added `NSAppleMusicUsageDescription` key in `info.plist`. But I can see spaces in both ends of key.

```
<key>..NSAppleMusicUsageDescription..<key>
```

It should be without space :

```
<key>NSAppleMusicUsageDescription</key>
<string>Play using while you are hiking</string>
```

Bonus: You can have space in your description.