# Empty build after upload app to Test Flight App Store Connect

Tags: xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I try upload new version of my app and I do it directly from XCode. After succesfull upload I do not see new build online on AppStore connect, but XCode says that upload is done.
As You see, 1.0.52 is created by Xcode but empty. 1.0.38 is my old build when all was ok. Any idea how to fix it? I can manually create iOS build on AppStore Connect and add package from my computer?
[image]

Comment: Thanks! You are right, now I fix it

Comment: Sometimes it just takes a few minutes for the upload to be fully processed.

Comment: yes, but unfortunately this time this was another problem. see answer to this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AppStore Connect didn't return any error, but now I found email on my developers email account. I missed one value at info.plist, similar problem like there: [NSAppleMusicUsageDescription - Missing Info.plist key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44742847/nsapplemusicusagedescription-missing-info-plist-key/44743146)
But about it I didn't have any information on AppStore Connect, only on email.

Part of email:

```
Dear Developer,

We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "**** ***" (***** ***). Please correct the following issues, then upload again.

ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist - Your app's code references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's Info.plist file should contain a NSAppleMusicUsageDescription key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the data. Starting Spring 2019, all apps submitted to the App Store that access user data are required to include a purpose string. If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these APIs, a purpose string is still required. You can contact the developer of the library or SDK and request they release a version of their code that doesn't contain the APIs. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/protecting_the_user_s_privacy).
```